# Using AVX with GCC: __builtin_ia32_addpd256 not declared

Tags: c++, gcc, avx, fma

If I `#include <immintrin.h>` I get this error:

> error: '__builtin_ia32_addpd256' was not declared in this scope

I have defined `__AVX__` and `__FMA__` macros to make AVX avilable, but apparently this isn't enough. There is no error if I use compiler flag `-mavx` instead of the macros, but that solution is not acceptable. So, what else should I define to use AVX?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on `-mavx` not being an option. Afterall using avx-intrinsics is kind of hard when the compiler isn't actually allowed to emit avx code

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be defining `__AVX__` and `__FMA__` yourself - these get defined automatically when you enable the correct compiler options, e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -mavx ...
```

You can check this yourself if you're interested:

No AVX:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "AVX|FMA"
$
```

AVX:

```
$ gcc -mavx -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "AVX|FMA"
#define __AVX__ 1
$
```

AVX + FMA:

```
$ gcc -mavx -mfma -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "AVX|FMA"
#define __AVX__ 1
#define __FMA__ 1
$
```

Comment: I've mentioned in the question that using `-mavx` is unacceptable. Thanks for showing the way to see defines, though.

Comment: Sorry - missed the last sentence in your question - how do you expect to compile AVX code if you don't enable this compiler option, and why would you even want to do this anyway ?

Comment: I expect to make `AVX` intrinsics declarations available by using correct defines, and I expect the implementation to be linked from the runtime library. What's the problem? The reason I can't use `-m` options is that in that case compiler vectorizes my code automatically using the specified instruction set, which leads to `SIGILL` on a CPU without AVX+FMA support. I need these instructions to only appear where I have used corresponding intrinsics explicitly.

Comment: Intrinsics don't work like that, and they don't link to anything - the general idea is that they generate inline code - if you look at the headers you'll see that each intrinsic maps to a `__builtin_XXX` which the compiler in turn uses to generate the relevant inline opcodes. If you don't enable AVX then the compiler can't process the `__builtin_XXX`s.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, it's the `__builtin` symbol I'm having problems with. Are you sure it's not a regular function?

Comment: No it's most definitely not a regular function - remember that each intrinsic generally maps to a single CPU *instruction* - a function call per instruction would more than wipe out any potential benefit from using SIMD.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: The intrisics would be completely pointless, if they mapped to regular (non inline) functions to be linked again. For a lot of operations the overhead of a function call could easily overshadow the costs of the operation itself, exspecially since that would prohibit leaving the data in the ymm register it is currently residing in

Comment: It sounds like the real problem here is that you are trying to generate common code which runs on both AVX and non-AVX platforms - you may need to try a different approach to achieve this.

Comment: Yep, I'll have to ask another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution might be to have a specific file that contains the processor specific intrinsic. And you set *-mavx -mfma* options only to this file. The program itself determine which version to call at runtime.

I use GCC helpers to get the best optimized version at runtime.

func_avx_fma.c

```
void domagic_avx_fma(...) {}
```

func_general.c

```
void domagic_general(...) {}
```

helper.c

```
void domagic_avx_fma(...);
void domagic_general(...);
typedef void (*domagic_func_t)(...);
domagic_func_t resolve_domagic()
{
     __builtin_cpu_init();
     if (__builtin_cpu_supports("avx") && __builtin_cpu_supports("fma")) {
         return domagic_avx_fma;
     }
     return domagic_general;
}
void domagic(...) __attribute__ ((ifunc ("resolve_domagic")));
```

program.c

```
void domagic(...);
int main() { 
    domagic(...);
}
```

To compile

```
$ gcc -c func_avx_fma.c -o func_avx_fma.o -O3 -mfma -mavx
$ gcc -c func_general.c -o func_general.o -O3
$ gcc -c helper.c -o helper.o
$ ...
```

This approach works great on x86 (x86_64) but not all targets support these helpers